# Is there a way to prevent an unanswered question to sink into oblivion?

Tags: discussion

I would like to know if there is a way to bump an unanswered question in Askubuntu, or something, before it sinks into oblivion?
Thank you

Comment: Also a highly-referenced question from meta.stackexchange — http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions

Answer (score 11):

There are a lot of different ways to "bump" your question (or others that you're interested in). One way is to edit it **adding more information**, like documenting what you've tried, more data about the issue, etc. Performing minor edits just to bump your question will eventually make the question a Community Wiki and you'll no longer gain reputation on that question.

If you've added everything you possibly can, you have the ability to add a [bounty](https://askubuntu.com/faq#bounty) to a question. This adds the question to a [list of featured questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=featured) which users browse and answer frequently.

Comment: I don't understand this "will eventually make the question a Community Wiki and you'll no longer gain reputation on that question" and this "you have the ability to add a bounty to a question" and this:"this adds the question to a list of featured questions which users browse and answer frequently". But the problem with adding details, even when I find them very important, is that very often someone comes with the scissors, edits my question and converts it into his question.

Comment: @RobertVila if your question is editied by another user and is changed too much you can do 2 things,  1. Re-edit the question yourself  using the existing edit as a guide to make the question better.  or 2. If the question has been so changed you can "rollback" the edit to the original question in 2 click.  Just click on the edited "X mins ago"  link and then you can use the rollback button to go back to the original question or to whichever edit is best.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have just re-edited a question to test this, but it does not appear in recent questions.

Comment: @RobertVila it will not appear in "newest question" it will be bumped to the top of the tab of "active" however

Comment: Ok, thank you TrailRider, and Sorry, Marco, I didn't realize there were links to the concepts I don't understand.