# How to get more viewer in an unanswered own question for a new user?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

As a new user of Ubuntu I am facing a lot of problem but getting help from the StackExchange's biggest community and learning something new and also sharing my experience. I have [an unanswered question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718752/password-in-wifi-hotspot-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-not-working) for many days. So I want to learn how a new user can get more view in an unanswered question.
I have found following links useful:

1. [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)
2. [Is there a way to prevent an unanswered question to sink into oblivion?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5354/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-an-unanswered-question-to-sink-into-oblivion)

But both link suggested by adding new data and editing question which doesn't help me. And moreover discussed to set a bounty whereas user needs [at least 75 rep points](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) to set a questions as bounty, which a new user doesn't have. And also suggested to upvote and I know it is not possible to upvote in an own post.

Correct me if I am wrong please giving me some links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, this question will help a lot with the views (If you added [the question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718752/password-in-wifi-hotspot-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-not-working) to this one) :)

You can also edit the question, this will push it to the top of the `active` queue. You can also [offer a `bounty`](https://askubuntu.com/help/bounty) on your question to give more users a reason to spend more time on the issue.

These are the things you can do to bring some more attention to the question but with regards to this specific question, it is quite niche as not to many users would use the `hotspot` function, as you say yourself there could be no known solution and in that case no one can help.

Unfortunately, not all questions are created equally and the more niche often receive less attention and some questions are doomed to never be answered.

My suggestions for you would be `edit` in as much extra information you can and stick a bounty on it, or delete that question (don't double post) and open a new one making an effort to add new information. You never know who is browsing the forum right now, and making the question active again could be what you need.

Comment: I have found that posting in Meta adding links to unanswered question helps a new user like me. I accept your answer @mark kirby.